# Drag and drop detection

Tags: javascript, events, dom, drag-and-drop

My task was only to detect when element is in drop zone/leaves drop zone/dropped in drop zone. Can someone explain me why browser isn't detecting drop event.

```
content2.addEventListener("dragenter",function(){
console.log("Pic is in drop zone.");
},false);


content2.addEventListener("dragleave",function(){
console.log("Picture is no longer in drop zone");
},false);

content2.addEventListener("drop",function(){
console.log("Picture dropped in drop zone");
},false);
```

I know that drop is by default disabled, but adding line `this.preventDefault()` in drop event didn't make any difference.

***Here is JS Bin link:***http://jsbin.com/ledur/2/edit

Comment: it needs to be `event.preventDefault()` where `event` is a passed argument to the callback, not `this.preventDefault()`

Comment: @PatrickEvans still no working...

Comment: @PatrickEvans still no working. I'have already tried this before posting question here. Here is JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ledur/3/edit

Comment: I am getting the console messages,even the `drop` event console message, in the javascript console. What is not working? What browser are you using?

Comment: the answer you posted worked, error was in using `this` instead `e` in `dragover`. Re post your answer so I could select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `preventDefault` in `drop` and `dragover` events

```
content2.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

content2.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
  console.log("Pic is in drop zone.");
},false);

content2.addEventListener("dragleave",function(){
  console.log("Picture is no longer in drop zone");
},false);

content2.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Picture dropped in drop zone");
},false);
```

[Modified JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wuxoyuhunidu/1)